# Tikz Drawing of sin^2y and cos^2y

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can someone please help me draw a graph of sin^2y and cos^2y? I tried writing the code for it but I am having a hard time because I do not know how to define the functions in terms of y for the domain. Thank you!

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.  Are you wanting y on the horizontal or vertical axis?  If horizontal, you can graph sin^2 x and then label it "y".

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
\tikzset{>={Latex[width=3mm,length=2mm]}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \filldraw[fill=olive!10,draw=white] (-3,-6.5) rectangle (3,7);% bkd color
        \draw[white](-3,-6.5) grid (3,7); % grid
        
        %scale on the axis
        \foreach \x in {-3,-2,...,3}
            \draw (\x,.1)--(\x,-.1) node[below]() {\footnotesize $\x$};
        \foreach \x in {-6,-5,...,6}
            \draw (.1,\x)--(-.1,\x) node[left]() {\footnotesize $\x$};
        
        % x & y axis
        \draw[->,line width=.5pt] (-3,0)-- (3.5,0) node[below]() {$x$};
        \draw[->,line width=.5pt] (0,-6.5)-- (0,7) node[left]() {$y$};
        
        
        % change data for function(s) to plot in the next lines
        \draw[rotate=-90,smooth,magenta,mark=none,domain=-6.5:6.5,line width=1pt] plot (\x,{sin(\x r)*sin(\x r)});
        
        \draw[rotate=-90,smooth,green,mark=none,domain=-6.5:6.5,line width=1pt] plot (\x,{cos(\x r)*cos(\x r)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would probably be better to `plot ({f(\x)},\x)`.  With rotation, it only comes out correctly by chance.  If that's what OP wanted.

Comment: @Teepeemm Yes I know. In another answer I apply this way.